# How to implement a closure for this function in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, closures

Last night, I Googled  a lot and couldn't find the solution for my problem:
I have a `for` loop with one function in it which gets me only the latest value from the array.

So, here is the example:

```
obj1.route = new Routeng();
obj2.route = new Routeng();

for(var x in arrObjs) { //arrObjs = array of objects
  var g = arrObjs[x];

  // I can access properties of all "g" objects

  Routelousse.gen(function(res) {
    var pathern = res.pathern;
    g.routel.staviPather(pathern);

    MYOBJ.vehicles.push(g);
    alert(g.name); // during the loop I always get the LAST "g" object from "arrObjs"
  }, g.point);

}
```

Comment: Not clear (to me) what you're asking for?

Comment: @annakata - Because JavaScript doesn't have block scope here, the same `g` is re-used every `for` loop pass, so the incorrect one is being used when that asynchronous function completes.

Comment: @Nick - yeah I understand block scope thanks, what I didn't understand is what the desired result was. But you did it seems so the customer's happy.

Comment: Are you sure you googled a lot? ;) [JavaScript Closures for Dummies](http://blog.morrisjohns.com/javascript_closures_for_dummies.html)(Example 5) is quite helpful...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It should look like this:

```
obj1.route = new Routeng();
obj2.route = new Routeng();

for(var x=0; x<arrObjs.length; x++) {
  var g = arrObjs[x];

  (function(ig) {
    Routelousse.gen(function(res) {
      var pathern = res.pathern;
      ig.routel.staviPather(pathern);

      MYOBJ.vehicles.push(ig);
      alert(ig.name);
    }, ig.point);
  })(g);
}
```

In this we're passing the current `g` into that self-executing function as a different variable, rather than the `g` which is shared in the function you're currently in (this isn't block scope) and is changing each pass of the `for` loop.

Also note the `for` loop change...you should never use a `for...in` loop to *iterate* an Array, use a normal `for` loop for that.